# Unable to empty a file despite sudo privileges

Tags: shell, sudo, io-redirection

I have a file that is owned and written by `root` user.

I have another user called `systemuser` that we have given sudo privileges for every action.

I'm able to perform every action by `systemuser` just like how i do for `root` user.

But I'm trying to null a file owned and written by root and I get permission denied error.

```
 >api-server-out-0.log
-bash: api-server-out-0.log: Permission denied
$ sudo >api-server-out-0.log
-bash: api-server-out-0.log: Permission denied
```

Note: a process running with `root` user is currently writing to this log file.

Can you please suggest how can I using `systemuser ?

Comment: Your code looks messed up. Edit question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo > api-server-out-0.log
```

won't work. What it actually does, it starts `sudo` without any parameters and tries to redirect its output **under your user account** to the specified file which of course will not work since the file is owned by root.

What you really want to do is something like

```bsh
sudo dd if=/dev/null of=api-server-out-0.log
# or
sudo truncate -s 0 api-server-out-0.log
# or
sudo sh -c 'echo -n "" > api-server-out-0.log'
# or
sudo sh -c ': > api-server-out-0.log'
```

Comment: What it dose is: … do re-directions, … execute commands (in this sudo something). So the root privilege arrives too late.

Comment: `echo -n ""` outputs `-n<SPC><NL>` in UNIX-compliant implementations of `echo`. Standard commands that produce no output and are generally builtin include `true`, `eval`, `test 1`, `[ 1 ]`, `:`, `printf ''`... In `sh`, you can also do `> file` alone.

Answer (score 1):

[Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612608/40482) has described the "why" and offered some of the many options.  Here's another way to go about it:

```
sudo tee api-server-out-0.log </dev/null
```

Comment: Also `sudo cp /dev/null file`.